# Double integral where inner integrand is with respect to $y$ first

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

My question:
$$\iint_D  xy \,dA\,,$$ where $D$ is the region bounded by $y = x - 1$ and parabola $y^{2} = 2x + 6$

[image]

Quick question, what does the inner integrand represent?

Anyway here's how I set up the double integral with respect to y as the inner integrand:

$$\int_{-1}^{5} \int_{-2}^{4} xy \,dy \,dx$$
$$\int_{-1}^{5} \int_{-2}^{4} (y+1)y \,dy \,dx$$
$$\int_{-1}^{5} \int_{-2}^{4} (y^2 + y \,dy \,dx$$
$$\int_{-1}^{5} \left[\left(\frac{y^3}{3} + \frac{y^2}{2}\right)\right]_{-2}^{4} \,dy \,dx$$

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

Limits $[-1,5] \times[-2,4]$ gives whole rectangle and cannot be true. If you "stay" on axis $OY$ having head up to $OX$ direction, then floor is $y^{2} = 2x + 6$ and roof $y=x-1$.

So you have limits
$$\left\{\begin{array}{}
-2 \leqslant y \leqslant 4\\ 
\frac{1}{2}y^2-3 \leqslant x \leqslant y+1
\end{array}\right\}$$
i.e.
$$\int\limits_{-2}^{4}\,dy\int\limits_{\frac{1}{2}y^2-3}^{y+1}  xy  \,dx$$

Comment: is your dydx in the right order?

Comment: Different sources have different suggestion on this order - outer integral is by $y$ inner by $x$ - I made replacement to avoid ambiguous.